# Email as a string

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to login to a website using scrapy and I need to use an email as a username, but when it uses the username instead of using an `@` symbol in the email it does `%40` instead.  Is there a way to prevent this?  Because I obviously cannot login right now because of this problem.

**LoginSpider.py**

```
import scrapy
from ..items import NameItem

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "LoginSpider"
    start_urls = ["https://www.starcitygames.com/login"]

    def parse(self, response):

        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'ex_usr_email': 'example@123.com', 'ex_usr_pass': 'password'},
        callback=self.after_login
        )


    def after_login(self, response):
        item = NameItem()
        item["Name"] = response.css("div.column_data::text").get()
        return item
```

**Partial Output**

```
2019-06-20 16:23:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6027
2019-06-20 16:23:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.starcitygames.com/login> (referer: None)
2019-06-20 16:23:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.starcitygames.com/results?name=&go=GO&ex_usr_email=example%40123.com&ex_usr_pass=password> (referer: https://www.starcitygames.com/login)
2019-06-20 16:23:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.starcitygames.com/results?name=&go=GO&ex_usr_email=example%40123.com&ex_usr_pass=password>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your log it seems that you call wrong form on the page, not login form.

Try to specify it in code with:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formcss='#existing_users form',  # <- set this selector for form
        formdata={'ex_usr_email': 'example@123.com', 'ex_usr_pass': 'password'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )
```

Now I got html-response with:

> Your email address and/or password does not match the email address and/or password on record for this account. Please try again.

But I am sure if you pul correct credentials, everything will be fine.